# Splitting dataFrame using spark python

Tags: python, json, pyspark

I'm using dataframe in spark to split and store data in a tablular format. My data in file looks as below -

```
{"click_id": 123, "created_at": "2016-10-03T10:50:33", "product_id": 98373, "product_price": 220.50, "user_id": 1, "ip": "10.10.10.10"}
{"click_id": 124, "created_at": "2017-02-03T10:51:33", "product_id": 97373, "product_price": 320.50, "user_id": 1, "ip": "10.13.10.10"}
{"click_id": 125, "created_at": "2017-10-03T10:52:33", "product_id": 96373, "product_price": 20.50, "user_id": 1, "ip": "192.168.2.1"}
```

and I've written this code to split the data -

```
from pyspark.sql import Row
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
import pyspark.sql.functions as psf

spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .appName("Hello") \
    .config("World") \
    .getOrCreate()

sc = spark.sparkContext
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)

ratings = spark.createDataFrame(
    sc.textFile("transactions.json").map(lambda l: l.split(',')),
    ["Col1","Col2","Col3","Col4","Col5","Col6"]
)

ratings.registerTempTable("ratings")

final_df = sqlContext.sql("select * from ratings");
final_df.show(20,False)
```

The above code works fine and gives the below output :

[image]

As you can see from the output the `"click_id and number"` is being shown, similarly `created_at and timestamp` is being shown.

I want to actually have only the values in the table - click_id, created_at, product_id and so on.

How do I get only those values into my table ?

Comment: You mean, removing the keys (`click_id, created_at` etc) and keeping only the values for all 6 columns?

Comment: @desertnaut Yes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your map function, parse the json object instead of splitting it

```
map(lambda l: l.split(','))
```

should become

```
map(lambda l: json.loads(l))
```

(after you have imported json)

```
import json
```

Also if you remove the columns definition

```
["Col1","Col2","Col3","Col4","Col5","Col6"]
```

you will get the columns from json

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to use only the dataframe API, then you could use the following code:

```
ratings = spark.read.json("transactions.json")
```

This will load the json into a dataframe, mapping the json keys into column names. 
Then you can select and rename the columns with the code below.

```
ratings = ratings.select(col('click_id').alias('Col1'),
                         col('created_at').alias('Col2'),
                         col('product_id').alias('Col3'),
                         col('product_price').alias('Col4'),
                         col('user_id').alias('Col5'),
                         col('ip').alias('Col6'))
```

This way you can also cast columns into relevant datatypes, e.g. `col('product_price').cast('double').alias('Col4')` and properly save to database.

Comment: Is there a way to store individual column name as list and pass each of those values as parameters ?

Comment: If i understood correctly what you mean, you could have an array, e.g. `arr = ["Col1","Col2","Col3","Col4","Col5","Col6"]` and do `df = df.select(arr)`

Comment: For example - I want to store the click_id into a list/array and pass each of those values arr[0], arr[1] to a function get_value(click_id) which takes click_id as input parameter @geopet

Comment: You can try `df.select('click_id').rdd.flatMap(lambda x: x).collect()` which will produce an array of all click_id values, which can be handled as you wish.